# PHP Reflection Not Working on Sub-Class

Tags: php, pdo

Pardon me, I might have to show a lot of code for you guys to understand my problem.

So, I am creating a poor man's ORM in PHP, I have a static class `SQLQuery` which handles connection and building of queries, and a `BaseModel` class that makes use of the `SQLQuery` class. All custom models inherit from the `BaseModel`.

My problem is, I try to use reflection to get the properties from the calling sub class, but it does not return these back, even though it returns the methods that are in the class. Below are my codes.

```
namespace BB8\Potatoes\ORM\System;
use BB8\Potatoes\ORM\System\StaticSQLQuery;

class BaseModel
{
    protected static $tableName;
    protected static $subClassName;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::initializeQuery();
    }

    public static function initializeQuery()
    {
        if (static::$tableName == null) {
            static::$tableName =  end(explode("\\", get_called_class()));
        }
        static::$subClassName =  get_called_class();
        static::$tableName =  strtolower(static::$tableName);
        StaticSQLQuery::init(static::$tableName, static::$subClassName);
    }



    public static function find($id)
    {
        static::initializeQuery();
        return StaticSQLQuery::selectWhere(array("id"=>$id));
    }


   public function test()
   {
        $rc = new \ReflectionClass(get_called_class());
        return $rc->getproperties();

   }
}
```

I create a new class `Users` as below:

```
namespace BB8\Potatoes\ORM\Models;
use BB8\Potatoes\ORM\System\BaseModel;

class User extends BaseModel
{
    protected static $tableName = "Users";

    public function getName()
    {
        return "This is the name function for this";
    }

}
```

from the `index.php` I try

$user = User::find(1);
which returns a User class using `$STH->setfetchmode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Users')`

when I dump : `var_dump($user);` I get

```
object(BB8\Potatoes\ORM\Models\User)[5]
  public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'full_name' => string 'George James Okpe' (length=17)
  public 'description' => string 'There is no knowledge that is not power' (length=39)
  public 'token' => string '196' (length=4)
```

The problem is when I run

```
$user->test();
```

it  only returns properties in the `BaseModel`, I am frustrated and do not know what to do.

PS: I know there are better ways to frame this question, but my brain is not working properly now, because of all the stress.

Please guys I need your help

Comment: In BaseModel in "find" method try to use static::initializeQuery() instead of self::initializeQuery(). That would use late static bindning in order to return object of proper child class, and not of a class where method "find" was defined.

Comment: I used that, does not work either

Comment: I just discovered something funny, when I place the property in the User class it displays, but when I add it from outside it does not...